# output seconds in hh:mm:ss format relative to how many seconds

Tags: php

I have created a function which converts any amount of seconds to the format `hh:mm:ss`. It works fine at the moment, however, I'd like it to be a little bit more *refined* than it currently is.

This is what I currently have:

```
// 65 seconds
$t = round(65); 

// this will output 00:01:05
echo sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", ($t/3600),($t/60%60), $t%60);
```

What I want it to output instead, is something along the lines of this:

```
// 11 -> 0:11
// 60 -> 1:00
// 1200 -> 20:00
// 3600 -> 1:00:00
// 36000 -> 10:00:00
```

I have been searching around, however, I haven't come across anything that functions how I need (or even similar, so that I can alter it).

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: From your description, if the number of seconds is not up to 3600 (ie less than one hour) you want the output to just be mm:ss such that only with more than 3600 will there be an output of hh:mm:ss. I'm I correct?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest YouTube, Twitter and Facebook all display less than 60 second videos with that time format.. So it can't be that bad

Comment: You already have a one line code that uses as close to SPL code as possible, which means it will be fast. It also produces the right output. I really don't get what you mean by "more refined".

Comment: @Makville I don't mean more refined as in faster, I mean it as I need the output format to be more refined..

Comment: So you don't want the prefix "00"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go with a minor modification of your code. 
I believe your code is actually very fast since you use native functions.

Here goes

```
function format_time($t) {
     $t = round($t); 
     return ($t < 3600 ? sprintf("%d:%02d", ($t/60%60), ($t%60)) : 
          sprintf("%d:%02d:%02d", ($t/3600),($t/60%60), ($t%60)));
}
```

Outputs are exactly as you specified in your question.
Cheers.

Comment: May I suggest a tiny modification to your code? Just to make it a bit cleaner, you could just do this `$t = round($data->runtime); echo ($t < 3600 ? sprintf("%d:%02d", ($t/60%60), ($t%60)) : sprintf("%d:%02d:%02d", ($t/3600),($t/60%60), ($t%60)));` as a whole :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've got. Let me know if there's anything better:

```
<?php

$d = new DateTime();
$t = 122;
$d2 = new DateTime();
$d2->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString("$t seconds"));


$diff = $d->diff($d2);

$formatted = "";
if ($diff->h) {
    $formatted .= $diff->format("%H").":";
}
if ($diff->i || $diff->h) {
    $formatted .= $diff->format("%I").":";
}

$formatted .= $diff->format("%S");

echo $formatted;
```

Prints:

> 02:02

Example:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ea13ec5a2c37e48bcf5c2228be15f490e6ba0595

Note: This assumes a duration of less than 1 day, however you can extend the above a bit

Comment: If you go above 1 hour, it still displays as only `01:00`. Also, I need to be able to use `60`, not `"60 seconds"` :// thanks for the answer though! :D

Comment: I've updated that, I don't understand the restriction of using a number and instead of a dateinterval format you can just set `$t` to whatever you want and this will work the `seconds ` part is internal to how this works and you don't need to provide it externally.

Answer (score 0):

This works too. Date creates the format and uses a two preg_replace to remove hours and/or minutes.

By setting the timezone to UTC the date will output the correct time.

**Edit; I have now managed to do it with one regex**

```
$t = 11;
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
Echo preg_replace("/^00:0|^00:|^0/", "", date("H:i:s" , $t));
```

https://3v4l.org/ErkXg